# Почему 012 * 20 = 200?

Tags: java

Как это вышло, почему ответ 200?

```
int a = 012;
int b = 20;

System.out.print(a * b)
//result 200
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, если число начинается с 0, то используется восьмеричная система, то есть у вас a = 10. Странно что ответ 200, должен быть 100. Попробуйте вывести отдельно a и b, что там?

Comment: Извиняюсь  указал вместо 20 число 10.

Comment: Интересно каким образом определяется система исчисления в переменной?

Comment: Вообще говоря там только восьмеричная, десятичная и шестнадцатеричная (`0xff`).

Comment: оформлю тогда ответ как положено

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Java целочисленные литералы можно представить в разных системах счисления:

Если число начинается с `0x` - используется шестнадцатеричная.
Если с `0b` - двоичная.
Если начинается просто с нуля - используется восьмеричная, как раз как в вашем случае.
В остальных случаях используется десятичная система счисления.

То есть получается, что `a = 012` и `a = 10` это одно и то же.

Comment: про двоичную забыли

Comment: `System.out.println(0b110); // 6`

Comment: @rjhdby я про нее и не знал. Добавил про нее.

Comment: А `0oNNN` в Java работает?

Comment: @AlexeyTen проверил в 10 версии, где есть var, там не работает. Только с простым нулем.